# Unable to set breakpoints in my Eclipse JUnit tests

Tags: eclipse, debugging, junit, breakpoints

I’m using the following version of Eclipse/STS:

```
Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201506290652
Platform: Eclipse Mars (4.5.0)
```

In my editor, when I double click on a line number to create a breakpoint, the green breakpoint circle appears but with a slash through it.  Incidentally, I have noticed that when I run a JUnit test in Eclipse (by right clicking on the test name, selecting “Debug As” -> “JUnit Test”), execution never halts on that breakpoint.  I assume the two things are connected.  How do I create breakpoints that will actually halt execution in my JUnit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enabled `Skip all breackpoints` option. See below. Disable it.

[image]